# How would I do this query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

How can I do this in laravel query builder? (this basically gets your current position in a voting system)

```
SELECT position FROM 
    (SELECT participant.target_user_id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as position FROM 
        (SELECT target_user_id, count(*) as votes FROM contest_participants_votes GROUP BY 
        target_user_id ORDER BY votes DESC) as participant 
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r) x
WHERE target_user_id = 1
```

Comment: Unclear. What is the problem with that code ?

Comment: This is pure SQL, I want to do this in laravel query builder so I don't have to think about sql injection.

Comment: @user3542112 Your use of placeholders like `target_user_id = ?` protects you against injection.

Comment: So I should use a raw statement then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used a raw statement like this with placeholder

```
$position = \DB::select(\DB::raw(
            'SELECT position FROM 
                (SELECT participant.target_user_id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as position FROM 
                  (SELECT target_user_id, count(*) as votes FROM contest_participants_votes GROUP BY 
                  target_user_id ORDER BY votes DESC) as participant 
                JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r) x
            WHERE target_user_id = ?'), [$pid]);
```

Comment: `\DB::select(\DB::raw('query'), $attributes)` is how it should be, I guess.

Comment: What's the difference between this and with raw? I've tested it works. 

I just have to do $position[0]->position to get the value though

Comment: `raw` returns an object, `select` actually performs a query. But when you don't wrap your raw query with a `raw` then `select` will try to use the string as column names.